# size of dataframe/rdd in spark 3.2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was using

```
spark_session._jsparkSession.sessionState().executePlan(
     df._jdf.queryExecution().logical()).optimizedPlan().stats().sizeInBytes()
```

and pyspark with `version<3.2` in order to get the size of my DF (in bytes), but in 3.2 it seems the signature of `executePlan` [has changed](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c04aa36b7713a7ebaf368fc2ad4065478e264d85/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SessionState.scala#L122) and i get the following error

```
py4j.Py4JException: Method executePlan([class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Filter]) does not exist
```

Is there anyway to make this work? I tried adding

```
spark_session._jsparkSession.CommandExecutionMode
```

to the function call, but it produced the following error:

```
{AttributeError}'JavaMember' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the approach that you are trying with

Hers is the alternative approach to your problem.

df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda x,it: [(x,sum(1 for _ in it))]).collect()

Comment: does this provide the size in bytes/KBs, etc.? If I'm not wrong, this'll output the number of rows per partition

Comment: This does not provide the size in bytes, only a complicated way to count

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```py
size_bytes = spark._jsparkSession.sessionState().executePlan(
    df._jdf.queryExecution().logical(),
    df._jdf.queryExecution().mode()
).optimizedPlan().stats().sizeInBytes()
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77174735/5421064