# Optimizing pyspark code by calculating Dataframe size

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, optimization, aws-glue

I'm using the following function (partly from a code snippet I got from this post: [Compute size of Spark dataframe - SizeEstimator gives unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492463/compute-size-of-spark-dataframe-sizeestimator-gives-unexpected-results/77174735?noredirect=1#comment136090604_77174735)

and adding my calculations according to what I understood will be distributed within the workers based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvF7tY2-L3U  and ended up with the function below:

```
def get_partitions(df):
    partitions = 1
    df.cache().foreach(lambda x: x)                                                   
    df_size_in_bytes = spark._jsparkSession.sessionState()\
             .executePlan(df._jdf.queryExecution().logical(),\
             df._jdf.queryExecution().mode()).optimizedPlan()\
             .stats()\
             .sizeInBytes()
    kilo_bytes = int(df_size_in_bytes/1024)
    mega_bytes = int(kilo_bytes/1024)
    parts = int(mega_bytes/128)        
    if parts <= 0:
        parts = partitions
    else:
        partitions = parts   
    return partitions
```

Though is giving me the following error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o8705.mode. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method mode([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I'm working with AWS Glue jobs and interactive sessions, and in glue jobs I get an empty trace, and in Glue interactive sessions I get the error above, what is missing in the calculation. I'm currently using Spark 3.1 and Glue 3.0. any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spark version that Glue 3.0 uses does not accept the "mode" parameter for the executePlan(), introduced at [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/8013f985a4d07a948b0c22638314162819bfb2be) commit to the Spark core.

So, you just need to remove the parameter from the method call:

```
from math import ceil

def get_partitions(df):
    partitions = 1
    df.cache().foreach(lambda x: x)                                                   
    df_size_in_bytes = spark._jsparkSession.sessionState() \         
        .executePlan(
            df._jdf.queryExecution().logical()
        ).optimizedPlan() \
        .stats() \
        .sizeInBytes()

    mega_bytes = df_size_in_bytes/1000**2
    parts = ceil(mega_bytes/128)        
    partitions = 1 if parts == 0 else parts

    return partitions
```

Comment: @ 100chou Thank you so much for the reference, I'm testing it right now. this will save me more days on debugging the issue I'm facing with my code.

Comment: You're welcome. I adjusted the code because I realized the conversion between bytes to megabytes is wrong, nothing too problematic, just to be accurate.