How to calculate Dataframe size?
In Pyspark, How to find dataframe size ( Approx. row count : 300 million records) through any available methods in Pyspark.? My Production system is running on < 3.0 spark version. The idea is based on dataframe size i need to calculate shuffle partition number before joining

Please refer discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492463/compute-size-of-spark-dataframe-sizeestimator-gives-unexpected-results

thanks for your response .But my df have 300 million records and not recommended use cache.. The mentioned url suggested to use cache first and can take approx. size.

You can do this programmatically. We need to calculate each partition size and sum to get the data frame's total size. To calculate total size we need to write a function. Here's a sample code. I have tested it. This way you can calculate the size of the dataframe.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
    
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("MemSize").getOrCreate()
    
     
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Marks", IntegerType(), True)
])
    
num_records = 1500
data = [(f"Name{i}", i % 100) for i in range(1, num_records + 1)]  
     
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
    
 
    
""" 
    Converting df into rdd and used mapPartititions. 
    The iter contains rows present in that partition. 
    The sum  is used to compute the total size of all rows in a partition, in bytes.
"""

def estimate_dataframe_size_via_rdd(df):
    
    partition_sizes = df.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iter: [sum(len(str(row).encode("utf-8")) for row in iter)]).collect()
    
    total_size = sum(partition_sizes)
    return total_size
        
estimated_size_bytes = estimate_dataframe_size_via_rdd(df)
print(f"DataFrame size: {estimated_size_bytes / (1024**2):.2f} MB")


thanks for your code. I think for small size dataframe it will work. For larger dataset , is that good approach

BTW , i tried another approach calculated data size for data sample. but it is not maching with original size. The original size is : 30 GB :(

Using mapPartitions() is efficient even on larger df. The other way is to write to S3 and get the df size.

I need to calculate the df at runtime instead of writing into s3

mapPartitions()- first it will materialized  then convert to rdd and finally every partitions do calculate row one by one. I think it is not the best approach to solve this problem.

I tried with mapPartitions() approach. it doesn;t work.

Use the .count() function. See the documentation for this function, it should exist from spark 1.3.0 upwards. If an approximate count is enough, this page explains that you can use the .approxCount() function, but you first have to convert to RDD. Might be efficient as an exact count is usually not necessary for a shuffle partition number.

sorry .. i think you understand my question wrongly. I am NOT asking a row count. Need size of  the dataframe

You mean in terms of MB/GB/TB?

yes..you are right . found that the scala have sizeestimator api to get df size. But unfortunetly python doesn't have the api

another findings. Convert Pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe and  get the size. But the problem is all the data will move from executor memory to driver memory. this approach won;t work if you work large datasets

To find the approximate size of a DataFrame in PySpark, especially when dealing with a large number of records (around 300 million), you can use the count() method to get the row count. Since your production system is running on Spark version < 3.0, you can use the following approach:
Assuming 'df' is your DataFrame
row_count = df.count()
print(f"Approximate row count: {row_count}")

This will give you the total number of rows in the DataFrame. Based on this count, you can then calculate the number of shuffle partitions before performing a join operation. A common heuristic is to set the number of shuffle partitions to a multiple of the number of cores available in your cluster. For example:1
Set the number of shuffle partitions
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", desired_number_of_partitions)

You can determine desired_number_of_partitions based on your cluster's resources and the size of your data. A typical starting point might be 200 partitions, but you may need to adjust this based on performance observations.
